# onbeforeunload not working inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple react-component where a user can edit data. As the values that may be changed could take some time I want to ask the user to confirm when leaving the page in case of unsaved changes.

In the component's constructor I call:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleWindowBeforeUnload);
```

I also tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = this.handleWindowBeforeUnload;
```

The `handleWindowBeforeUnload` looks like this:

```
private handleWindowBeforeUnload = (ev: BeforeUnloadEvent): string => {
    return "Unsaved changes. Are you sure?";
}
```

However, setting a breakpoint will hit. But nevertheless there is no prompt showing that leaving may be dangerous. Also tried with latest Firefox but nothing happened.
As stated on MDN I also tried

```
// Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
e.preventDefault();

// Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
e.returnValue = '';

// return something to trigger a dialog
return null; // ''; // "Do something"
```

Still nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This might be a no-brainer dummy question and I'm sorry to ask but just to be sure: did you set the returnValue/prevent default *before* the `return` line? (eg you don't early-return before it actually happens)

Comment: I tried returning `null`, `''` as well as a string `Do something` at the very end of the function - Nothing happened. I know that custom strings or alerts will not be shown/are not supported. But at least the dialog (as written everywhere) would be great to see...

Comment: So I wonder if you bind on mount instead it will work. But as to why that would work when it doesn't in the constructor I'm not sure!

Comment: Ah someone just answered with that as well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to call the method inside the lifecycle methods:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleWindowBeforeUnload);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleWindowBeforeUnload);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is working (when also using the Chrome-fix). Any idea why it's working only when bound in `componendDidMount`? At least when bound in constructor I got a hit on my breakpoints (which means something has been bound).

Comment: In react, if you need to handle DOM events not already provided by React you have to add DOM listeners after the component is mounted

Comment: To implement these with hooks, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks

Comment: Question: Why do we have to remove it?

Comment: I am refacting a old react16 project, that's useful

Answer (score 5):

### Modern React Solution

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const preventUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
    // NOTE: This message isn't used in modern browsers, but is required
    const message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = message;
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', preventUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', preventUnload);
  };
}, []);
```

You may also need this depending on your lint config:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
event.returnValue = message;
```