# How to invoke constructor logic in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React doc says:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

But what if I want to invoke a logic that has to be triggered before component mounts?

Comment: for example? `useEffect` can be used to do something at only the first render, so that could be what you're looking for.

Comment: No it doesn't. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I guess all the code invoked before return(); will be executed before mounting

Comment: you don't need any hooks for that

Comment: @sudheersingh [Read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks/60866524#60866524), maybe it could help you.