# Update State in redux in background after every few minutes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to run a background process which would run a function every few minutes to call backend API and update the redux state. It is a large React App which has lot of components. This affects globally so I am looking for just a background process to do this.

I am looking if someone has done this before or used a ReactJS library to do it.

Comment: Tried using it via `setInterval`? Similar example: https://github.com/ccPrathap/sai-eog-react-assessment/blob/master/src/components/DroneVisualization.js#L19

Comment: @PrathapReddy Like I mentioned it is a big react component. What if the user is on a different page. Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: You can have all such calls in you main file like `App.js`. Will that be an issue in you case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `setTimeout()` function.

All you have to do is, inside your main root component, let's assume your root component is `App.js`. you can do the following.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      /* Your API call */
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      /* allYourComponents */
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a component like `BackgroundTask` and put it in your page with a useEffect inside :

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    // call you action here
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [])
```

And add it to the App component :

```
export default App => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BackgroundTask/>
        ... rest of your app ...
     </Provider>
);
```

Comment: So I will to put this BackgroundTask in every component? What if the user is on a different page. Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: No just inside your App (Main) component

Comment: @NotTheBestAnswer, Will the clean up (`return () => clearInterval(timer)`) really work? Because of empty dependencies `[]`, the effect run only for the first time after component has rendered.

Comment: @PrathapReddy yes it should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks