# How do i fix the React useEffect timing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am converting React Lifecycles to Hooks. App.js page is loading the first page's data before axios & store configs are run. Because of this, the wrong axios.baseURL is being used in the apis.

I replaced componentWillMount with useEffect, but it runs after the useEffect used on the first loaded page.

**APP.JS**

```
const App = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await AxiosConfig.init())();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await Store.init())();
}, []);

return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            ...
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

}

**LOADING PAGE**

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);    

const getData = useCallback(filters => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        let response = await DataService.getAllData(filters);
        if (response && response.status === 200) {
          let data = response.data && response.data.result;
          setData(data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => getData(filters), [filters, getData]);

<List data={data} />
```

How do i fix the timing so the config runs first? Do I need to combine the calls in one useEffect, set a flag upon success responses, and only return the App.js DOM if flag = true?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818036/4360136.

Comment: Do the `AxiosConfig.init()` and `Store.init()` calls have any dependencies on the UI being mounted? Can they initialized once when instantiated and imported, before react starts trying to render `App`??

Comment: Those files don't depend on the UI to be present. they are just config that sets up axios defaults and creates a store. Creating useComponentWillMount seems to work

Comment: I guess why not initialize them *before* react is loading your app, i.e. something like init them and pass them to the `ReactDOM.render` with the provider there?

Comment: "and pass them to the ReactDOM.render with the provider there" - sorry, I don't understand what you mean by this. do you have a code sample?