# How to trigger useEffects before render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, use-effect

I have a prop being passed from a parent component to a child component which changes based on the user's input.

I want to trigger a data fetch in the child component when that prop changes before the child component is rendered. How can I do it?

I tried in the following manner by using `useEffects(()=>{},[props.a, props.b])` but that is always called after the render. Please help!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function parentComponent() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ a: "", b: "" });
  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={inputs.a}
        onChange={(event) => {
          const value = event.target.value;
          setInputs((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, a: value };
          });
        }}
      />
      <input
        value={inputs.b}
        onChange={(event) => {
          const value = event.target.value;
          setInputs((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, b: value };
          });
        }}
      />
      <ChildComponent a={inputs.a} b={inputs.b} />
    </>
  );
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updating new data based on props.a: " + props.a);
    setData({ name: "john " + props.a });
    return () => {};
  }, [props.a, props.b]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data successfully changed");
    console.log(data);
    if (Object.keys(data).length !== 0) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [data]);

  function renderPartOfComponent() {
    console.log("rendering POC with props.a: " + props.a);
    return <div>data is: {data.name}</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">{isLoading ? null : renderPartOfComponent()}</div>
  );
}
```

In the console what I get is:

```
rendering POC with props.a: fe 
rendering POC with props.a: fe 
updating new data based on props.a: fe 
rendering POC with props.a: fe 
rendering POC with props.a: fe 
data successfully changed 
Object {name: "john fe"}
rendering POC with props.a: fe 
rendering POC with props.a: fe
```

If you know how I can make the code more efficient, that would be a great help as well!

Here's the codesandbox link for the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-northcutt-6z9f8?file=/src/App.js:0-1466

Comment: do you think this answer would help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818036

Comment: @Abhilash Thanks for the reply, but the approach that's been talked about in that answer is more of how to run a piece of code once when the component mounts, but in my case everything works fine the first time the component mounts, however when the props changes the return ( ) block renders before the useEffect is called, which is an issue because I want to fetch appropriate data for the new props

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you considered using cleanUp function in useEffect? I believe the steps goes as follows: cleanUp function in useEffect is called -> render is called-> then non-cleanUp useEffect function is called.

Comment: I fear this is post an XY Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F).). You are asking how to make React change it's fundamental behaviours as opposed to explaining what app behaviour  (or "business outcome") you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by creating and maintaining state within the ChildComponent

So, the order of processes was this:
props modified -> render takes place -> useEffect block is executed.

I found the workaround by simply instantiating a state within the childComponent and making sure that the props state is the same as the one in the child component before rendering, else it would just show loading... This works perfectly.

Comment: If you feel inclined to show a simple code demo that'd be great

Answer (score 26):

## Solution using useMemo

You can use `useMemo`, which doesn't wait for a `re-render`. It will execute as long as the dependencies are changed.

```js
useMemo(() => {
    doSomething() // Doesn't wait until render is completed 
}, [dep1, dep2]);
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it!

Comment: It's not something `useMemo` is supposed to do and a better practice would be redefining a new custom hook based on it. See my answer

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays you can use `useLayoutEffect` which is a version of `useEffect` that fires before the browser repaints the screen.

Docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect

Comment: Is this better solution than `useMemo`?

Comment: Although it runs before render, but unlike `useMemo`, it still runs after the other codes and also React's documentation states it can hurt performance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use function below:

```
// utils.js
const useBeforeRender = (callback, deps) => {
    const [isRun, setIsRun] = useState(false);

    if (!isRun) {
        callback();
        setIsRun(true);
    }

    useEffect(() => () => setIsRun(false), deps);
};

// yourComponent.js
useBeforeRender(() => someFunc(), []);
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: This hook allows you to run functions in stateless components before rendering (as componentWillMount).

Comment: Well, you could just use a `useMemo`. That does exactly what your custom hook does but additionally supports return values.

Comment: @Martin, yeah, a good solution, thank you

Comment: this example has an issue — setIsRun will trigger second render

Comment: @YuryPetrov use solution with useMemo, and cut off re-renders by returning null in main component before return jsx

Answer (score 6):

**useEffect** is always called after the render phase of the component. This is to avoid any side-effects from happening during the render commit phase (as it'd cause the component to become highly inconsistent and keep trying to render itself).

- Your **ParentComponent** consists of **Input, Input & ChildComponent.**
- As you type in textbox, `ParentComponent: inputs` state is modified.
- This state change causes ChildComponent to re-render, hence **renderPartOfComponent** is called (as isLoading remains false from previous render).
- After re-render, useEffect will be invoked (Parent's state propagates to Child).
- Since `isLoading` state is modified from the effects, another rendering happens.

Answer (score 1):

As `useMemo` is supposed to be used only to improve performance and reduce extra renderings with returning a `"memoized"` value, you can redefine a new custom hook:

```
// Redefined only to prevent confusion with useMemo
const useInit = (callback, depends = []) => useMemo(callback, depends)

// ...
useInit(() => {
  // Some initial calculations
})
useInit(() => {
  // Some initial calculations with dependencies
}, [depend1, depend2])
```