# Set hook's state once

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why when I run:

```
  interface Xxx {
    str: string
  }

  const [xxx, setXxx] = useState<Xxx>();

  function getData() {
    setXxx({
      str: "aaa"
    });
  }

  getData()
```

then the hook is being set all the time and forever. How to run `getData` once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use componentWillMount() in React Hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks)

Comment: `useEffect` with empty dependency array

Comment: Because every time this component renders you set xxx and every time you set xxx the component re-renders

Answer (score 3):

To execute your method only once on the component init, you can use the hook useEffect :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, []);
```

This is similar to react lifecycle method `componentDidMount`.

Some documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects