# How to play a sound when a new order is placed using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am building this PWA with ReactJS.

As the title says, I just want to play a sound whenever a new order is placed.

I am using the Context API in order to manage the states.

This is my **OrderContext.js** where I fetch the orders from the API using React Query.

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import apiClient from "../EventService";

export const OrderContext = createContext();

export const OrderProvider = (props) => {
  const fetchOrders = async () => {
    const { data } = await apiClient.getEvents();
    return data;
  };

  let { data: orders, status } = useQuery("orders", fetchOrders, {
    refetchInterval: 15000,
    refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
    notifyOnStatusChange: false,
  });

  return (
    <OrderContext.Provider value={[orders, status]}>
      {props.children}
    </OrderContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then somewhere in my **OrdersList.js** component, I just use the state and map through it:

```
{orders.map((order) => (
     <Order key={order.id} order={order} />
))}
```

And lastly, in my **Order.js** component is where I check if there is a new order or not:

I am using this function to check  if the order has been placed 15 or less minutes ago.

```
const isNewOrder = (orderCreatedDate) => {
    if (moment().diff(moment(orderCreatedDate)) / 900000 <= 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

and then in the in the JSX of the component I simply do this to display a badge on the new orders:

```
  {isNewOrder(order.date_created) && (
        <Badge style={{ padding: 3 }} content="Nuevo" />
   )}
```

I am having troubles adding a sound effect to these new orders, I tried using Howler but couldn't make it work properly.

If someone could help me or maybe show me a way to achieve this I would really appreciate. I can provide the full components if needed, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day!

Comment: When you say you are having trouble, what happens exactly? Are there any errors? What is the actual result?

Comment: The sounds are playing really buggy, and they are triggering everywhere, like literally if you click anywhere on the website, they play.

Comment: We would need to see the code that you are using to play the sounds the. There are a lot of missing pieces right now. I understand it can be a lot of code to paste, you could also provide a github or other code repository.

Comment: Here is the full component Order.js, where I am using howler: https://jsfiddle.net/q5tbj0vd/ and here is the buggy noise I am talking about https://imgur.com/Q82CTxS

Comment: As you can see in the component, I am just using sound.play() where I return true in the function, but it creates this weird behaviour

Comment: Are you using the same component to show the orders in the order list? If so it would trigger it multiple times.

Comment: yes I am using this component as you can see in the main post. I am not sure how to make it work or play the sound only when a new order is received

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach is to add a prop to your `Order` component and check if you are on the order list page or on the order page. If on one single order then you call `sound.play`, otherwise you do not.

Also, you should use [React Howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-howler) if you're not already. Regular Howler does not play well (no pun intended) with React.

Finally, you should add a `componentWillUnmount` function to stop the sound from playing (just call `sound.stop()` inside `componentWillUnmount`).

Comment: Oh I see, the only problem is that I am using React Hooks, my components aren't class component. What's the equivalent of componentWillUnmount?

Comment: You can use the `useEffect` function and place the code to stop the sound playing inside an anonymous function inside the return statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks for details.

Comment: I tried to use React Howler and it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't play any sound