# Why is useEffect firing AFTER the component is mounted (NextJS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using a `useEffect` as a `componentWillMount`, but it is behaving unexpectedly.

In `Component`, (as you can see in the Codesandbox below), the code in `useEffect` *should* fire before the `return` content is hit, but for some reason, the `useEffect` is entered after the DOM has loaded.

In the below sandbox, I'm loading two images, `imgsSrc1` and `imgsSrc2`. In my `useEffect`, I'm creating an image DOM element, and setting its `src` prop to `imgsSrc1`. In my `return`, I have an `img` element that has its `src` prop set to `imgsSrc2`.

I would expect `imgsSrc1` to start downloading first, but when I look into the network tab of the dev console, I see that `imgsSrc2` starts downloading first:

[image: img1]

Why is this happening? Is this NextJS behavior?

[image: green-water-gjdhz]

Comment: [`UNSAFE_componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) is deprecated (and `useEffect` was never a stand in for it as per the answer below) ...lifecycle overview here: [The Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

useEffect will always behave this way

It is firing after the component is mounted and then you need tell it to render again the component with the new data you got after it runs the code in your useEffect  function

From the official website :

"
**By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after performing the DOM updates.**
"

useEffect will run after the first render

"
**Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.**"

Hopefully, it's more clear now.

If not, try looking through the documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: So, does this mean I can't create a `componentWillMount` hook? I'd have to implement a [hacky way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62701724/2891356)?

Comment: The standard use is to conditionally render the first render then update/initialize when useEffect runs then show on second render.

Comment: they change the way component did mount works so you can , maybe this will help you more ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464595/how-to-use-componentwillmount-in-react-hooks?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: if i answered your question can you mark my answer as the answer >? please ?