# WC3 Sensors in React Web

Tags: reactjs, w3c, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to get [W3C](https://github.com/w3c/sensors) Sensors API working inside my React Web App (Not React Native), basically I cannot find any reliable documentation for getting it to work using javascript, this is the code I produced so far:

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  export default class Postion extends Component {
  state = {
    message: "not supported",
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.test();
  }

  test(){
    if(window.Accelerometer){
        this.setState({message:"supported"})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.message}</div>;
  }
}
```

It displays "supported" on desktop browsers and "not supported" on all the mobile browser I tried so far, so my question is: how can I get data from the accelerometer using the sensors API (especially on mobile browsers)? I can even be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet. But there's nice documentation always on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Accelerometer):

```
let acl = new Accelerometer({frequency: 60});

acl.addEventListener('reading', () => {
  console.log("Acceleration along the X-axis " + acl.x);
  console.log("Acceleration along the Y-axis " + acl.y);
  console.log("Acceleration along the Z-axis " + acl.z);
});

acl.start();
```

---

Now, to implement it on React, you know the deal. Just need to hook in componentDidMount hook.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, I've allready tried this solution, but I keep getting "Accellerometer is not defined", since I'm not that familiar with hooks can you please provide me a working example? Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52449059/2138752

Comment: Also, I'm not stating about react hooks but just stating that you're already familiar with `componentDidMount` hook. A hook here is to simply state a method.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but what does your reply has to do with the problem?

Comment: You asked how to bind listener in react, that's what I suggested.

Comment: Ok now I got it: basically the library is binded as an event on the window did it?Thanks, now is so much clearer

Comment: No. The linked post in my comment  only shows how to bind the listener in react. And here in the answer provided shows how to use Accelerometer using `reading` listener. And you should follow the docs linked in the answer. Hope, you got it fully now.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, but as stated, I'm getting "Accellerometer is not defined", is not releated on how to use listeners at all.

Comment: That means not supported.